# Celery worker and command line args

Tags: python, celery

I am refactoring my code to use celery worker.

Before I used to use argparse to pass command line args.

e.g.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Node')
     parser.add_argument('--environment', action="store", default='local', help="env e.g. production of development")
     environment = arg_options.environment
```

But now I get this error.

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info --environment local
celery: error: no such option: --environment
```

How can I add?

I don't want to use environment variable if I don't have to.

```
e.g export environment=development
```

Answer (score 10):

The Celery worker does not execute your `__main__`.

If you want to add additional command-line options you can use `app.user_options`,
but note that it uses the `optparse` module, not `argparse`.

See this section in the docs for more:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/extending.html#preload-options

Comment: I understand how to get arguments into a bootstep __init__ method, but how do I then access these parameters from a task?

Comment: Or how to get them... at all frankly.  hours lost on this

Answer (score 7):

By looking at the source code, I've figured out a way to handle this.

On celery.py add:

```
from celery import bootsteps
from celery.bin import Option

....
app.user_options['worker'].add(
    Option('--server', dest='api_server', default='127.0.0.1',
           help='API server to use.')
)

app.conf['API_SERVER'] = '127.0.0.1'

class ConfigBootstep(bootsteps.Step):
    def __init__(self, worker, api_server=None, **options):
        app.conf['API_SERVER'] = api_server

app.steps['worker'].add(ConfigBootstep)
```

Then in the file holding your tasks add this:

```
from celery import current_app
...
@shared_task()
def roboscope():
    API_SERVER = current_app.conf.get('API_SERVER', '127.0.0.1')
```

I tried making API_SERVER a module global variable by resolving it when the module is imported but it doesn't work as it's too early. As my task is quite intensive it doesn't harm to run this many times.

Comment: You can use `bootsteps.StartStopStep` class as a base instead. This way you can get the value earlier (and save it in variable or something) and even validate the value of your argument when the worker starts.

Comment: "on celery.py add:" forgive me - but you shouldn't collide with celery's namespace. Choosing 'celery.py' will  certainly break a multi-module application.

Answer (score 0):

Can use worker option.

For example, I had to initialise mongo database in one of the task

```
from celery import bootsteps
from celery.bin import Option
import mongoConfig
.....


app = Celery('scraper')

app.user_options['worker'].add(
    Option('--mongo', dest='is_mongo_required', default=None, help='Mongo Required')
)

class CustomArgs(bootsteps.Step):

    def __init__(self, worker, is_mongo_required=None, **options):
        # store the api authentication
        if is_mongo_required is not None and is_mongo_required[0] == "true":
            print("Mongo initialization required")
            mongoConfig.init(required=True)


app.steps['worker'].add(CustomArgs)


app.config_from_object('celeryConfig')
```

Command to execute

```
celery worker -A scraper --concurrency=4 --loglevel=info -Q abc,bcd --mongo=true
```