# Celery transfer command line arguments to Task

Tags: python, persistence, celery, celery-task

I am struggling with transfering additional command line arguments to celery task. I can set the desired attribute in `bootstep` however the same attribute is emtpy when accessed directly from task (I guess it gets overriden)

```
class Arguments(bootsteps.Step):
  def __init__(self, worker, environment, **options):
    ArgumentTask.args = {'environment': environment}

    # this works
    print ArgumentTask.args
```

Here is the custom task

```
class ArgumentTask(Task):
  abstract = True

  _args = {}

  @property
  def args(self):
    return self._args

  @args.setter
  def args(self, value):
    self._args.update(value)
```

And actual task

```
@celery.task(base = ArgumentTask, bind = True, name = 'jobs.send')
def send(self):
  # this prints empty dictionary
  print self.args
```

Do I need to use some additional persistence layer, eg. persistent objects or am I missing something really obvious?

> [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365101/celery-worker-and-command-line-args)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible. The reason for that is that your task could be consumed anywhere by any consumer of the queue and each consumer having different command line parameters and therefore it's processing should not depend on workers configuration.

If your problem is to manage environment dev/prod this is the way we managed it in our project:

Each environment is jailed in it's venv having a configuration so that the project is self aware of it's environment(in our case it's just db links in configuration that changes). And each environment has its queues and celery workers launched with this command:

```
/path/venv/bin/celery worker -A async.myapp --workdir /path -E -n celery-name@server -Ofair
```

Hope it helped.

If you really want to dig hard on that, each task can access a `.control` which allows to launch control operations on celery (like some monitoring). But I didn't find anything helpful there.

Comment: I guess that applies to persisting objects between tasks impossible? E.g. if I set some property in my custom task and then execute a chain of tasks, they wont have that property set. Is that right?

Comment: The same applies. Anything you want to want to jump from tasks to tasks have to be serialized and put into the queue along with the next tasks to executes as arguments, or have to be persisted in a database. The way I did that kind of stuff is by persisting metadata in my objects (in mongodb for that matters) and putting tags ("task X begin/end")

Comment: I was afraid of that... I will have to rethink few things. Thanks